# Modifying the query for view

Tags: sql, view, oracle11g

One of our views used to return a single row and a single value, which used to be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Due to certain data changes in the concerned tables, with the same criteria in WHERE clause as before, now we are getting two rows being returned from the system.

Let's assume the underlying table, **test** has two values as of now.

```
COLUMN
------
TRUE
FALSE
```

I can write a CASE statement to check the count of the records being returned from the current view, by encapsulating the entire code for view in an inner query, something like

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN count(a.val) > 1
             THEN 'TRUE'

          ELSE a.val
       END
FROM (
SELECT val FROM test) a;
```

What I am not able to do is, how to check for the records which are being returned by the inner query - I need to suppress the two records, and return only one record, as in if I am getting TRUE and FALSE as output, I should only return TRUE. In case, I am getting both records as TRUE or both as FALSe, I should return TRUE/FALSE respectively.

How can I get this done within the view?

Comment: cast the boolean to int and use max

Comment: Thanks @Evgeni This is neat and serves the purpose. If you can post it as answer, I will accept it!

Comment: Distinct in the inner query should help you to avode "I am getting both records as TRUE or both as FALSe, I should return TRUE/FALSE respectively."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the boolean to int and use max:

```
select max(cast(mybool as INT)) from MyView
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as to return only the first row :

```
ELECT CASE 
          WHEN count(a.val) > 1
             THEN 'TRUE'

          ELSE a.val
       END
FROM (
SELECT val FROM test where rownum = 1) a;
```